DSE LifeCycle Manager can't upgrade to newest version
I can't perform an upgrade to the latest version of DSE via Lifecycle Manager. Specifically, it's that I can't point to a version higher than 6.8.43 (that's also the current version used on nodes). Both on the server with OpsCenter and on all hosts to be upgraded there are DSE packages version 6.8.47 available in the repo.
    yum search all dse --showduplicate | grep "6.8.47"
dse-6.8.47-1.noarch : This package contains the full dse distribution.
dse-demos-6.8.47-1.noarch : This package contains the dse demo applications.
dse-full-6.8.47-1.noarch : This package contains the full dse distribution.
dse-libgraph-6.8.47-1.noarch : This package contains the dse graph libraries.
dse-libspark-6.8.47-1.noarch : This package contains the dse spark libraries.
dse-libcassandra-6.8.47-1.noarch : This package contains the dse cassandra libraries.
dse-libhadoop2-client-6.8.47-1.noarch : This package contains the dse hadoop 2 (client) libraries.
dse-liblog4j-6.8.47-1.noarch : This package contains the dse log4j libraries.
dse-libsolr-6.8.47-1.noarch : This package contains the dse solr libraries.
dse-libtomcat-6.8.47-1.noarch : This package contains the dse tomcat libraries.

Until recently, it worked seamlessly. Now it's like this:

What is the problem?

The symptoms you described indicate to me that the OpsCenter definitions files are out-of-date.
OpsCenter ships with a set of files that define things that include supported DSE versions, supported monitoring metrics, and JVM options among other things. These definitions files can be updated independently so you don't have to upgrade your OpsCenter installation to unlock new features.
OpsCenter regurlarly checks the opscenter.datastax.com repository for new definitions and downloads them to update the files in your installation. If OpsCenter is not able to obtain the latest definitions, check that the server has access to the site.
If you have disabled automatic updates, you will need to manually update the definition files. For details, see Updating and configuring definitions files properties. Cheers!
